# Android NDK use kernel libs / drivers (so)

Tags: android, android-ndk, kernel, shared-libraries

I currently developing app for Android that provides various audio settings. I use android system prepared by someone else, and it provides (I see in source and compiled files) some methods that could be useful for me. For example there are (kernel/drivers/audio/audio.c) some methods to change bands (for equalizer). In compiled system there is audio_setting.so file in some audio dir on kernel. Is there a possibility to use this methods (library) in my application NDK? I don't want to compile my app with whole system, rather to dynamically add this lib.

edit:
It was simplier than I thought. I used:

```
void *some_lib;
bundlewrapper = dlopen("some/path/some_lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if ( some_lib!= NULL ) {
    LOGV("Loaded lib\n");
    // use methods from lib
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use any code on the system.
Obviously if it is non-JNI code you'll have to call it from your own JNI code or wrapper.

In your Android.mk file you will need to add the extra lib in LOCAL_LDLIBS